# Pass angularjs variable to nodejs function from view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Is it possible to pass angularjs variable to a nodejs function from view like below

```
// View
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <img src="<%getUserImage(user)%>">
 </div>

// Server
app.locals.getUserImage = function (user) {
    if (user.url) { return user.url; };
    return "/images/no-user.png";
}
```

I have the following error:
Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Can anyone help please ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you put a `console.log()` on the `user` in the server code to see if a `user` is actually being passed?

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo the server said "user" is undefined

Comment: That means the user isn't getting passed into the function

Comment: You can try a template engine like ejs, handlebars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you perform this operation in the view instead of having to call the server function?

Just like this

```
<img ng-src="{{ user.url || '/images/no-user.png' }}"/>
```